# How to write a string starting with ' and ending with " in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'd like to save the following characters `'bar"` as a string variable, but it seems to be more complicated than I thought :

- `foo = 'bar"` is not a valid string.
- `foo = ''bar"'` is not a valid string either.
- `foo = '''bar"''` is still not valid.
- `foo = ''''bar"'''` actually saves `'\'bar"'`

What is the proper syntax in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last string saves `'\'bar"'` as the representation, but it is the string you're looking for, just print it:

```
foo = ''''bar"'''
print(foo)
'bar"
```

when you hit enter in the interactive interpreter you'll get it's `repr` which escapes the second `'` to create the string.

Using a triple quoted literal is the only way to define this without explicitly using escapes. You can get the same result by escaping quotes:

```
print('\'foo"')
'foo"
print("'foo\"")
'foo"
```

Comment: Learned something today ;)